# PHASER - Access var of obj inside of group

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a group of objects and I want to access the object that is being touched (using game.physics.arcade.overlap) as I need to access one of its variables. Could anyone point me out any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the type of physics but I assume it's Arcade:

```
    function create()
    {
       ...
       bullets = game.add.group();
       bullets.enableBody = true;
       bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

       veggies = game.add.group();
       veggies.enableBody = true;
       veggies.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
       ...
       //Create veggies, bullets, etc...
    }

    function update() 
    {    
       ...
       game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, veggies, collision, null, this);
       ...
    }

    function collision(bullet, veg) 
    {
       console.log(bullet);
       console.log(veg);
    }
```

The "collision" function captures the group elements when the event occurs, you can use it for "[sprite vs group](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/sprite-vs-group)" or "[group vs group](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-group)" (with ARCADE physics)